# GRANT SELECT ON view TO user using script on SQL developer, than SELECT * FROM that view in SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

My script on SQL dev:

```
**CREATE USER C##DG IDENTIFIED BY abc123;**

**CREATE VIEW DG1_VIEW**
AS SELECT m_pms.MaPMS, m_pms.MaDG, m_pms.SoLuong, m_s.MaSach, m_s.TenSach, m_ctpm.SL
FROM PhieuMuonSach m_pms, ChiTietPhieuMuon m_ctpm, Sach m_s
WHERE m_pms.MaDG = 1 AND m_pms.MaPMS = m_ctpm.Ma_PMS AND m_ctpm.Ma_Sach = m_s.MaSach**;**

**GRANT CREATE SESSION TO C##DG;
GRANT SELECT ON DG1_VIEW TO C##DG;**
```

On Sql Plus, i logged in as C##DG, typed '''**SQL> SELECT * FROM DG1_VIEW;**'''
and received **'ORA-00942: table or view does not exists'**. But this view already had data.

What is my problem and how to fix it? I'd love to hear from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either specify schema this view has been created in

```
select * from system.dg1_view;
```

or you may login as system again and create a public synonym for that view in order to make it available without specifying schema

Comment: I created USER C##DG and View DG1_VIEW in SYSTEM using that code in the questions. Is there any wrong with that? Do i need to add something? Also, your solution didn't work.

Comment: @NguyenBot I've update the answer with user name. It should help

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @NguyenBot **DO NOT CREATE TABLES/VIEWS/OBJECTS IN THE `system` USER.** Create a different user, give it the appropriate permissions, etc. But do not use the built-in users which are designed to store data related to the system set-up. If you do then you risk making your system unusable when you inadvertently change some critical system data.

Comment: You also shouldn’t be writing user data to the root container (I’m assuming you’ve created a C## user so that you can work in the root). All user data should be in a pluggable database, which will not require special named users.